# Ruby method call with a symbol parameter with no space

Tags: ruby

I saw something in a Rails app I am reviewing that I expected to be an error, however it is working. I am confused by the way this method is being called with this parameter. No spaces, just two words separated by a colon:

```
    ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :001 > def muffin(x)
    ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :002?>   puts x.inspect
    ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :003?>   end
    => nil
    ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :004 > muffin:tuffin
    :tuffin
```

Also works with a string:

```
    ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :004 > muffin'd'
    "d"
```

Is this the expected and correct thing?

Comment: +1 for teaching me another trick of ruby's grammar. This language can get ridiculous. "#{muffin:tuffin}" is a syntax error.

Comment: Also `{}[muffin:tuffin]` tries to evaluate `tuffin` to create the hash key `{muffin: tuffin}`, so it fails w/ a `NameError`

Comment: `"#{muffin:tuffin}"` is not a syntax error for me. If you want crazy Ruby syntax, check out this one `$???::?$`

Answer (score 4):

Ruby enjoys one of the most relaxed grammars in the industry. Yes, the space is optional. And try `muffin(:tuffin)` if you want your colleagues to see what's going on.

Furtherless, you can write:

```
def muffin x
```

Yet another example of "because I can" isn't a valid reason for doing something. C-;

Comment: I came across this because of the following in a rails app:

        validates_presence_of:store_name,:message => "Please enter Store Name(2-50 characters)"

Very strange.

Comment: Why not `muffin2`,`muffin+2` are not allowed, but only *symbols* and *strings*?

Comment: The `_presence_of:store_name` is lazy, and both humans and editors should fight that. But `muffin2` satisfies the "maximum munch" rule - a parser reads a token for as long as it can find symbols which that token permits. So `muffin2` is a complete token, not two tokens, because identifiers are well-defined to permit numbers anywhere except the first character.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby methods can be called without parentheses:

```
puts 'string' #returns string
puts'string'  #returns string
```

In case of strings and symbols even the space is optional.

```
puts10 #NameError: undefined local variable or method `puts10' for main:Object
puts 10 #returns 10
```

Also note the difference that is introduced by the use of space:

```
[1,2,3,4].count + 1 #returns 5
[1,2,3,4].count +1  #returns 1 (calls method [1,2,3,4].count with +1 as an argument)
```